# In python, for a class variable supposed to be constant, is using literals faster than constructing it?

Tags: python, optimization, bytecode

I had big problem trying to explain it so i'll put the example.

Suppose I have a big tuple of data that's supposed to act like a constant. For this project, I was making a card-deck class so to make the tuple will all the base cards, but I was wondering about it too for larger data sets and how Python (standard C implementation) handles these optimizations.

I have two  options:

```
deckCards = []
for value in range(1,14):
    for suit in range(4):
        deckCards.append(Card(value,suit))
deckCards=tuple(deckCards)
```

Or:

```
deckCards = (Card(1,0), Card(1,1), Card(1,2),..)
```

The seconds maintenability is disastrous, and the first loop will result in the second expression in the end with extra operations between...

The critical thing I want to know is: once Python has interpreted it and converted to bitcode the deckCards tuple, will it stay as that data for the durantion of the program (or import from another module) or will it recalculate it (AKA reinstantiate it) EVERY time that i access the variable?

I know that Java and C# will optimize most const or static readonly vars and convert them to a single memory allocation to avoid recalculating, but I don't know how this works in Python.

Thanks for the answers in advance.

Comment: It will do that calculation exactly as often as you tell it to. Accessing a variable does not cause it to get recalculated. That would be insanity and destroy all normal expectations of imperative programming.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking. What do you mean by "access the variable"? For example `deckCards[0]` will not rebuild the tuple. In both approaches the time consuming step is the creation of the `Card` instances, not the loops.

Comment: Lots of languages do what you are hoping for. That is, once you get to the final assignment: `deckCards = ...`, then all the calculations have ceased, never to be repeated.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much.

I know it might sound crazy but it's something I wasn't quite sure with interpreted languages. I know Python creates a bytecode that contains the real code being executed (bytecode depending on the underlying implementation) but I didn't know if that bytecode was generated every time I accesed a module (he had to interpret the file again), or only once (he accesed the generated bytecode).